# React Query clean response function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a helper function to clean up the response from a useQuery call to an api.
Here is the function:

```
export const cleanResponse = function (data) {
  let x = [];
  let y = [];

  data.forEach((item) => {
    x.push(item.title);
    y.push(item.price);
  });
  return { titles: x, prices: y };
};
```

In my main components I'm using useQuery to get the data then applying the above function to clean it up and prepare it for plotting:

```
const {
    data: products,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = useQuery(['products'], () => {
    return axios('https://dummyjson.com/products/').then((res) => res.data);
  });

  const cleanData = cleanResponse(products.products);
  const titles = cleanData?.titles;
  const prices = cleanData?.prices;
```

Then I'm rendering a simple bar chart passing the data as props:

```
<BarChart titles={titles} prices={prices} />
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')
```

What am I missing here? Should my cleanResponse function be async because it's accepting data from an api?

Comment: I think the error is due to initial state `cleanResponse(products?.products || [])`. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while the query is still running, you component renders with `data:undefined`.

one way to solve this is to check for undefined before you do your transformation. Other approaches are doing the data transformation at a different time, e.g. in the query function after fetching:

```
const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = useQuery(['products'], () => {
     return axios('https://dummyjson.com/products/')
        .then((res) => res.data)
        .then((data) => cleanResponse(data.products))
  });
```

That way, the cleaned data will be stored in the cache already and `data` returned from `useQuery` will be the cleaned data.

Other approaches include using the `select` option. You can read more about that in my blog post about [react-query data transformations](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations).

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to initial state you can do as below to prevent error.

`cleanResponse(products?.products || [])`